# JQuery script for one checkbox selection from group not working while adding a checkbox dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

i'm using the below jquery script to disable user from selecting more than 1 check box of same name at a time

```
 $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

And here is the check boxes

```
 <div class="ChekMarkWrap">
  <input id="chkFilm_4" type="checkbox" name="four" style="margin-left:2px;" /><br />ﬁlm
 </div>

 <div class="ChekMarkWrap">
  <input id="chkTv_4" type="checkbox" name="four" /><br />tv
 </div>

 <div class="ChekMarkWrap">
  <input id="chkWeb_4" type="checkbox" name="four" /><br />web
 </div>

 <div class="ChekMarkWrap">
  <input id="chkStage_4" type="checkbox" name="four" /><br />stage
 </div>
```

It works well and good until i add a new check box dynamically.i'm binding the above jquery script on `document.ready()`

Comment: Why not use the `<radio>` element, which is designed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hcFp/2/

That method binds the `click` event only once, so elements added after that code has been run will not have the event bound. What you need to do is set up a listener instead, like so:

```
$('body').on('click', 'input:checkbox', function () {
    // Do some stuff
}
```

In the fiddle, i have wrapped the checkboxes in a `form#exampleForm`, and replaced `body` in the above example with that.

**EDIT:** Updated fiddle with live example of adding more checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
$("body").on('click',input:checkbox,function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).prop("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
});
```

When you add new content you need to append it to the DOM.

But you can target a parent element that was not added after the DOM was loaded to be able to reference/attach-event to it using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and passing the selector as I wrote above on the first line of your code..

Comment: This will not work. `on` has to be called on a parent element to sustain the binding when new elements are added. http://jsfiddle.net/3hcFp/5/

Comment: Yes it does. In your example you assume '.ChekMarkWrap' is also inserted dynamic, I didn't. We don't know the OP's markup. I will change to `$("body")` anyway, then it's more safe.

Comment: True, true. It's reasonable to assume though, isn't it? :)

Comment: Sant @NicklasNygren, helt rätt! och det var jag som tänkte fel på din kod först, sorry :) Ska vi radera detta?

Answer (score 0):

You should use delegated events. Your code is running on `document ready`. Nothing is bound to new elements.

```
$("your-form-selector").on('click', ':checkbox', function(){
//your code here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using delegates. Something like this:

```
$(".ChekMarkWrap").delegate('click','input:checkbox',function () {
    //your functionality
});
```

For Reference: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: `Delegate` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.